# How to listen to a socket from your backend?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket

I'm trying to set up a socket on my backend which listens to an api (that has a socket). Sorry might not be wording that correctly

I can get the frontend to listen to a socket, but I'm having trouble getting a response from the socket on my backend.

Is there some specific way I should call the socket from the backend?
I'm using nodejs

Here's an example of what I have

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');

function startSream () {// <-- called from app.js (express nodejs server)
    ws.on('open', function open() {
        ws.send("hiya other socket");
    });
    
    ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
        console.log(data);// <-- never gets called
    });
}
```

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong here?

Haven't found much information on linking a backend with a socket.

Edit: After testing a few things, this code does work

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");

function startSream () {// <-- called from app.js (express nodejs server)
    const ws = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');

    ws.on('open', function open() {
        ws.send("hiya other socket");
    });
    
    ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
        console.log(data);// <-- never gets called
    });
}
```

Problem is I need the ws var to be outside the function so I can close it

Comment: out of curiosity, is there a reason you're not make use of socket.io ?

Comment: @balexandre no reason at all. Am completely new to sockets so don’t really know what I’m doing haha. I’ll give socket.io a try too

Comment: then use socket.io, the library is very easy to use on the backend and the script to be loaded in the frontend is already cross-browser ready! - here, [start with this](https://socket.io/get-started/chat) 